# add ASN.1 generated class to C project

Tags: c, asn.1

I generated some C classes from an ASN.1 description with this compiler lionet.info/asn1c . When I trie to compile the code with GCC I have errors, this is a peice of them

> in file included from asn_application.h:45,
>                    from client.c:10: constr_TYPE.h:15:28: error: ber_tlv_length.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:16:25:
>   error: ber_tlv_tag.h: No such file or directory In file included from
>   asn_application.h:45,
>                    from client.c:10: constr_TYPE.h:35: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘ber_tlv_len_t’ constr_TYPE.h:38:60:
>   error: ber_decoder.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:39:68:
>   error: der_encoder.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:40:58:
>   error: xer_decoder.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:41:60:
>   error: xer_encoder.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:42:61:
>   error: per_decoder.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:43:61:
>   error: per_encoder.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:44:59:
>   error: constraints.h: No such file or directory constr_TYPE.h:77:
>   error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘ber_tlv_tag_t’
>   constr_TYPE.h:77: error: ‘ber_tlv_tag_t’ declared as function
>   returning a function constr_TYPE.h:77: warning: parameter names
>   (without types) in function declaration constr_TYPE.h:79: error:
>   expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before
>   ‘asn_TYPE_outmost_tag’ constr_TYPE.h:95: error: expected
>   specifier-qualifier-list before ‘asn_constr_check_f’
>   constr_TYPE.h:144: error: field ‘tag’ declared as a function
>   constr_TYPE.h:147: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before
>   ‘asn_constr_check_f’ constr_TYPE.h:157: error: field ‘el_tag’ declared
>   as a function In file included from client.c:11:
>   asn_codecs_prim.h:8:29: error: asn_application.h: No such file or
>   directory In file included from client.c:11: asn_codecs_prim.h:20:
>   error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before
>   ‘ber_decode_primitive’ asn_codecs_prim.h:21: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’,
>   ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘der_encode_primitive’ In file
>   included from client.c:15: ber_decoder.h:56: error: expected
>   declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘ber_tlv_len_t’

In eclipe a got

> Invoking: GCC C Compiler gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD
>   -MP -MF"src/BIT_STRING.d" -MT"src/BIT_STRING.d" -o "src/BIT_STRING.o" "../src/BIT_STRING.c" ../src/BIT_STRING.c:5:26: warning:
>   asn_internal.h: No such file or directory ../src/BIT_STRING.c:6:24:
>   warning: BIT_STRING.h: No such file or directory
>   ../src/BIT_STRING.c:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
>   '**attribute**' before 'asn_DEF_BIT_STRING_tags'
>   ../src/BIT_STRING.c:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
>   '**attribute**' before 'asn_DEF_BIT_STRING_specs'
>   ../src/BIT_STRING.c:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
>   '**attribute**' before 'asn_DEF_BIT_STRING' ../src/BIT_STRING.c:48:
>   error: expected ')' before '*' token ../src/BIT_STRING.c:76: error:
>   expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before
>   'BIT_STRING_encode_xer' ../src/BIT_STRING.c:141: error: expected ')'
>   before '*' token make: *** [src/BIT_STRING.o] Error 1

In eclipce I just added the generated classes in the src folder and added the headers.

Comment: You're going to need to give more info, such as a minimal example of what you're compiling, or the intermediate C code.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler errors look cryptic, but they’re designed to be read by humans. Usually the first error you see is the best indication of the problem (assuming there is only one).

```
in file included from asn_application.h:45, from client.c:10: constr_TYPE.h:15:28: error: ber_tlv_length.h: No such file or directory
```

So there is no header `ber_tlv_length.h` in the compiler’s search path. It looks like this is one of the headers that should be included with the lionet.info code. So figure out where these headers are, and either move them to a location you know the compiler is already searching for headers, or tell the compiler to look where they are (`-I/path/to/headers/`).